# Model always executing else clause when using WHERE clause

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with the function of the mode. When I put the right admin name and admin password, it doesn't work. Instead, it gives me the last error message ("You don't have..."), but if I comment out the second WHERE clause in my model, then it works as intended.

**Model:**

```
function validate_admin()
    {   
        $this->db->where('adminname',$this->input->post('adminname'));
        //$this->db->where('adminpassword',md5($this->input->post('adminpassword')));
        $query = $this->db->get('admin');
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }   
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
function validate_admin_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('adminname','Username','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('adminpassword','Password','trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['main_content']='login_failed';
            $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            if($this->admin_model->validate_admin())
            {
                $data = array(  
                    'adminname' => $this->input->post('adminname'),
                    'adminpassword' => $this->input->post('adminpassword'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                    );  
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('/site/admin_panel');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "You don't have administration privileges";
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

**Model**

```
$adminpassword = md5($this->input->post('adminpassword'));
$data = array('adminname' => $this->input->post('adminname'), 
              'adminpassword' => $adminpassword);
$query = $this->db->get_where('admin', $data);
return $query->num_rows();
```

**Controller**

```
if($this->admin_model->validate_admin() > 0)
```

Comment: `md5` move out `where`. You can try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely sure about password you can try this code:

```
$this->db->where('adminpassword', md5($this->input->post('adminpassword', TRUE)));
```

Edit: edited, sorry for my poor english

Comment: with the md5 is a problem. when i not set in my database the password to md5 and in model i delete md5 it works.